# Python3系でのJsonからの値の取得法について

Tags: python, json, python3

```
{'resultCount': 3,
 'results':
 [
  { 
   'collectionViewUrl': 'https://itunes.apple.com/jp/album/stab-me-in-the-back/id573901505?i=573901752&uo=4'
  }
  {...}
  {...}
 ]
}
```

という構造のJsonからキー"collectionViewURL"の値をPython3系で取得する方法を教えてください。

Comment: 気になったのは、[質問にあるJSONは不正です](https://jsonlint.com/?json={%0D%0A%09%27resultCount%27%3A3%2C%0D%0A%09%27results%27%3A[{%0D%0A%09%09%27collectionViewUrl%27%3A%27https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fjp%2Falbum%2Fstab-me-in-the-back%2Fid573901505%3Fi%3D573901752%26uo%3D4%27%0D%0A%09}]%0D%0A})ので、基本的にどんなパーサをつかってもエラーになると思われます。py3では2までと同様に[json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)などが使えますが、これもエラーを起こすかとおもいます。もし質問内容がこのようなlazyなjsonをパースする旨であれば、そのように追記してください。

Comment: JSONの文字列リテラルはダブルクオートしか使えないですね。

Answer (score 3):

既にコメントにも有る通り、記載されているJSONが不正なようですが、仮に正しくパースできるJSONだという前提で書いています。

Pythonには標準でjsonパッケージが含まれているのでそれを利用することができます。

```
import json

JSON_STRING = """
{
 "resultCount": 3,
 "results": [
  {
   "collectionViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/jp/album/stab-me-in-the-back/id573901505?i=573901752&uo=4"
  }
 ]
}
"""

json_obj = json.loads(JSON_STRING)
print(json_obj['results'][0]['collectionViewUrl'])
```